# mythbuntu-control-centre fails to run on Xubuntu 13.04

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

When mythbuntu-control-centre is installed on Xubuntu 13.04, it generates the following error immediately after it is executed from the command line:

```
**royg@MythTV:~$ mythbuntu-control-centre
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/mythbuntu-control-centre", line 40, in <module>
    from aptdaemon.gtkwidgets import (AptErrorDialog,
ImportError: cannot import name AptMessageDialog**
```

When it is executed from the Settings Manager - System dialog box, nothing appears to happen.

Comment: Have you reported this as a bug? If not, press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` (to open Terminal) and then copypaste: `ubuntu-bug mythbuntu-control-centre` to report the bug with log files. Thanks.
I suspect this is a problem with Ubuntu as a whole considering the flavours tend to be just a different desktop environment and slightly different programs on top of the same OS.

Comment: Tested on Lubuntu 13.04, I get exactly the same error. It's probably a general Ubuntu bug with mythbuntu-control-centre.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to resolve this error is to edit line 40 (or thereabouts) in /usr/bin/mythbuntu-control-centre, removing the now obsolete(!) reference to AptMessageDialog.

Note that you'll still want to keep the other 2 references in the import statement, so just insert a parenthesis at the end of line before, then delete the line containing AptMessageDialog) entirely.